# How to POST a String having length of more than 80k

Tags: android, vb.net, http-post

I am trying to send two images with some related string data. Images are in form of Base64 string. Total length of the parameters are about 81000

here is my code:

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);

            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            entityBuilder.addPart("uname", new StringBody(GlobalUname, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entityBuilder.addPart("pwd", new StringBody(GlobalPassword, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entityBuilder.addPart("imeino", new StringBody(IMEINumber, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entityBuilder.addPart("role", new StringBody(role_code, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entityBuilder.addPart("filexml", new StringBody(Msr_encryXmlFile, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entityBuilder.addPart("img1", new StringBody(images.get(0), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entityBuilder.addPart("img2", new StringBody(images.get(1), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

            HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();

            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
```

But i am getting "" (blank string) as response.
I tried these images to send as `FileBody` but still i am getting the same.

The above code works perfect with single image.

I tried with `HttpUrlConnection`

like this:

```
URL url = new URL(postURL);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            http.setDoOutput(false);
            Map<String,String> arguments = new HashMap<>();
            arguments.put("uname", GlobalUname);
            arguments.put("pwd", GlobalPassword);
            arguments.put("imeino", IMEINumber);
            arguments.put("role", role_code);
            arguments.put("filexml", Msr_encryXmlFile);
            arguments.put("img1", imagePath.get(0));
            arguments.put("img2", imagePath.get(1));
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("&");
            for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet())
                strBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            byte[] out = strBuilder.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            int length = out.length;

            http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.connect();
            /*PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(http.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.print(out);
            printWriter.close();*/
            http.getOutputStream().write(out);

int code = http.getResponseCode();
            String msg = http.getResponseMessage();

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

I am getting status code `400` as Bad Request.

how to get it done.

here is my server code:

```
Public Function getMustrollNew() As System.Xml.XmlElement Implements Imustroll.getMustrollNew
        Dim uname, finyear As String
        check = New HandheldErrorLOg
        download_id = Guid.NewGuid()

        Try

            Dim con1 As String

            finyear = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("finyear")

            uname = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("uname")
            'pwd = mps.decrypt(Split(mps.decrypt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("pwd")), "||")(0))
            pwd = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("pwd")
            Dim image1 as String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("img1")
            Dim image2 as String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("img2")
            imeino = mps.decrypt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("imeino"))

'Rest of code
        End Function
```

Comment: That is a server error. So show your server code.

Comment: `But i am getting "" (blank string) as responce. ` If there is a server error then you will not get a response further i think.

Comment: I am getting success result while sending single image.

Comment: `new StringBuilder("&");`. I see only one ampersand. You should have one for every following key=value pair too.

Comment: `getting "" (blank string)` An empty string?

Comment: with two image, server doesn't even getting the request as i checked with debugger.

Comment: I asked you to post the server code.

Comment: yes. An empty string. I have posted my server code too.

Comment: I dont see any file receiving code in the server code.

Comment: when I start in debugging mode and put breakpoint in finyear and uname and it doesn't even detect any request.

Comment: but when send a single Base64 string with rest of data, debugger halt at uname. and I am getting all value properly in my server code.

Comment: Not much fun helping you. `new StringBuilder("&");. I see only one ampersand. You should have one for every following key=value pair too`. You still did not react.

Comment: `"&"` is appending after each `key=value` pair as you can see its inside for loop.

Comment: No it does not.  There is no such code. Please add it.

Comment: `for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet())
                strBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));`

how should i write this line?

Comment: If you do not admit that you did not add ampersands then its not fun communicating with you. Or helping you.

Comment: sir, I'm just asking that isn't it a good way to add ampersands using a loop?

Comment: Adding ampersands in a loop is ok. But i see no ampersand(s) to begin with. I already said that 20 hours ago.

Comment: Sir, I started appending with `strBuilder` object which is already initialized with `"&"`.
its like:
`for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet())
                "&".append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: `its like`. You should be precice. And not post code that does not even compile. You have only one ampersand for the first key=value pair. The next ones do without. I said that 20 hours ago. Please log strBuilder.toString() and you will see only one ampersand.

Comment: please rewrite proper code whatever I should have to modify.

Comment: If you can append `key=value` then you should be able to append `&key=value`.

Comment: yes, I got your point and modified my code accordingly but the issue is still the same. And getting the same empty string with postman tool.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when I sent 3 images. Then now I fixed this issue.

First, check database field size. if the size of the field is smaller than Base64 string it will create the problem.

In my case, I used my moto g4 plus mobile to take images. when I take an image the size of an image is nearly 5MB. So, Base64 String gives a string length nearly 72,00,000. It is very big size. So. I could not successfully send the 3 images to the server. Then I reduced the image size to 250 kb. So, Base64 String gives a string length nearly 50k. It is a very big difference. After that, I can upload 3 images at a time successfully

Try the below code and let me know still you are facing the issue.

```
public static File file = null;
int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
public static Uri imageUri;

private void cameraActivity(){

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.US);
    Date now = new Date();
    String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".JPEG";

    Intent intentCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/", fileName);
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intentCamera, TAKE_PICTURE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentFromCamera) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentFromCamera);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {

        if(file.exists()) {

            ExifInterface oldExif = null;
            String OldExifOrientation = null;
            try {
                oldExif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
                OldExifOrientation = oldExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            scaleDown(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()), 400, true);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

            if (OldExifOrientation != null) {
                try {
                    ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, OldExifOrientation);
                    newExif.saveAttributes();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            sendImageRequest();
        }
    }
}


private void sendImageRequest() {

    String encodedImage = "";
    if(file!=null) {
        if(file.exists()){

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("path : ", "--" + file.getPath());
            Log.e("name : ", "--" + file.getName());
            Log.e("AbsolutePath : ", "--" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.e("length : ", "--" + encodedImage.length());
        }
    }

    **//your server request code here**
}

public Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize,
                        boolean filter) {
    float ratio = Math.min(
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getHeight());

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width,
            height, filter);
    saveToInternalStorage(newBitmap);
    return newBitmap;
}

private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: I already have compressed my images up to 30kb. but I'm having the issue while sending a request as I need to send two images with some related information to the server which is having total argument length of about 81k.

Comment: Try this and let me know. Instead of sending img2 argument as imagePath.get(1)); send img2 argument as imagePath.get(0));